# Python narrowing of generic type in function signature

Tags: python, generics, python-typing, narrowing

I'm having problems with generics and type narrowing in python. What I want is a generic list type and a filter function that selects elements by type. I have two goals:

1. The type argument of the filter function should be restricted to the possible types in the generic list.
2. The return type of the filter function should be as narrow as possible.

So far, I can only come up with solutions that achieve one of the goals but never both at once. Here is a code example:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T')
V = TypeVar('V')


class FooList(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.data: list[T] = []
    def filter(self, type__: Type[T]):
        return [d for d in self.data if isinstance(d, type__)]

class BarList(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.data: list[T] = []
    def filter(self, type__: Type[V]) -> list[V]:
        return [d for d in self.data if isinstance(d, type__)]


lst = FooList[int | str]()
lst.filter(float) # good: does not typecheck
filtered = lst.filter(int) # bad: filtered: list[int | str]

lst = BarList[int | str]()
lst.filter(float) # bad: does typecheck
filtered = lst.filter(int) # good: filtered: list[int]

# goal:
lst = BazList[int | str]()
lst.filter(float) # good: does not typecheck
filtered = lst.filter(int) # good: filtered: list[int]
```

I would expect a possible solution to define the function with `T` as argument and a narrower `V` as return type, but I don't know how to express this. Binding `V` to `T` (i.e. `V = TypeVar('V', bound=T)`) does not seem to work, as `TypeVar bound type cannot be generic`.

Comment: Alas, I believe this requires what's known as "HKTs" (Higher Kinded Types). What you want is to use the BarList structure, but then put the bound of V as T, so that V must be a subtype of T.

Comment: @Mark yes, I think so as well. I can also understand that `TypeVar('V', bound=T)` is not always possible. But I would expect that this works when V is a class var of BarList such that T is already known when V is bound.. But, seems like that is not supported.